# Try to Create On Click event on the button created with new record in datagridview

Tags: c#

Trying to create on click Listener on the button created with each record in dataGridView

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();

connection.Open();

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

command.Connection = connection;

command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM vc";

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

da.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

DataGridViewButtonColumn col = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();

col.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true; 

col.Text = "Folder";

col.Name = "MyButton";

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: i wanna to create a button with each record inserting to data base with some specfic link

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [DataGridView.CellClick Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick.aspx)

1. Try following code to add button ,

   ```
   // Add a button column. 
   DataGridViewButtonColumn buttonColumn = 
       new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
   buttonColumn.HeaderText = "";
   buttonColumn.Name = "MyButton";
   buttonColumn.Text = "Folder"; 
   buttonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
   ```
2. `CellClick` handler

   ```
   // Add a CellClick handler to handle clicks in the button column.
   dataGridView1.CellClick +=
       new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellClick);
   ```
3. And yes `dataGridView1_CellClick` itself for you stuff to work against a buttion click.One thing need to look at is ,

> You must need to look for button cell clicked, else it will be fired for each cell content click.

```
    void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        // Ignore clicks that are not on button cells. 
        if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex !=
            dataGridView1.Columns["myButton"].Index) return;
       ...... 
       you stuff....
    }
```